# Get a list of all the competitors assigned in all the teams in VueJS

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I have a list of teams. Each team has a list of assigned competitors.

Each team should have unique competitors.

How should I have the list of all the competitors assigned in VueJS???

```
"teams": [
  {
    "id": 25,
    "name": "t1",
    "competitors": [
      {
        "id": 1, 
        "short_id" : 1,
        ...
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "name": "t2",
    "competitors": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "short_id" : 4,
        ...
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "short_id" : 3,
        ...
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "short_id" : 5,
        ...
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 28,
    "name": "t3",
    "competitors": []
  }
]
```

[image: Assign Competitors to Teams]

Comment: Can you post that as a JSON structure?

Comment: Do you have any code so far ?

Comment: @BelminBedak I have the idea of how to do it manually, loop through teams, and merge each array of competitors, but as I don't manage so well JS and Vue, I don't know what is a good way to do it. I know how to do it hugly, or old fashion style, but don't know an elegant way to do it... but still no code

Comment: You can iterate over all items with `v-for` loop, if you have some nested data you can do another nested v-for loop - like this http://jsbin.com/bacuwasaqe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention, it will be a computed property

Comment: I a part of the screen, I have a list of teams. In the other parts, I have the full list of competitors. So the screen is to assign competitors to team. This computed variable will help me to remove the already assigned competitors in the list of competitors. I will add a screenshot for better understanding

Comment: @BertEvans Array changed to Json, check update in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    teams
  },
  computed:{
    competitors(){
      return this.teams.reduce((acc, team) => acc.concat(team.competitors), [])
    }
  }
})
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/wJPJZL?editors=1011).